# Trying to parse a date throws parser error

Tags: android, simpledateformat

Im trying to parse date of type 23-May-2016 and 24-May 2016 for instance..

Following code demonstrates how im parsing the date.

```
  SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date validityDate = null;
            Date nextDueDate = null;
            try {
                validityDate = format1.parse(mValidityDate.getText().toString());
                nextDueDate = format1.parse(mNextDueDate.getText().toString());
                int validate = validate(validityDate, nextDueDate);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Following is the code that finds the number of difference between two dates.

```
public static int validate(Date valid, Date nextDueDate) {
        return (int) ((nextDueDate.getTime() - valid.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24l));
    }
```

The problem is that, im getting Date parser error at offset 3. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different `SimpleDateFormat`

For date *23-May-2016* you need `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");`

For date *24-May 2016* you need `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the pattern "`dd-MM-yyyy`" which means you're trying to parse a date of the form `12-05-2016`.

If you need to parse a date such as "`12-May-2016`", then you have to use 3M letters for the month as follows. "`dd-MMM-yyyy`".
However, this will output "`12-Jun-2016`", if you parse the date "`12-06-2016`".

If you need the complete month, then you should use 4M letters. E.g: "`dd-MMMM-yyyy`". Then it will output `12-June-2016`.